# Принцип DIP из SOLID и Autowiring из DI-контейнеров

Tags: php, solid, di

Принцип DIP гласит: зависимости должны быть на абстракциях, а не от конкретной реализации.

Например такой код:

```
public function log(LoggerInterface $logger) { }
```

Зависимость от интерфейса.

При использовании DI-контейнеров с autowiring - работать не будет. 
Для работы автовайринга нужно, чтобы был указан конкретный класс в зависимости.

Объясните пожалуйста, что я не так понял? Или почему вижу противоречие в принципе DIP и инструмента для упрощения работы с зависимостями?

Comment: Противоречия нет. В том же DI контейнере вы указываете какую из реализаций интерфейса использовать. Ну и фишка использовать абстракцию более глобальна. При замене реализации вы не будете переписывать все методы, где эта реализация используется.

Comment: Тогда смысл автовайринга, если мы вручную указываем в контейнере ?

Comment: Смысл в том, что вы в любой момент (в одном месте) можете сменить реализацию в контейнере, а не по всему коду приложения.